# How to close all tensorflow sessions currently open, or at least find that ones are open?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to understand tensorflow. Been working for some time on it in my jupyter notebook. Each time i run tf.reset_default_graph() i get a

> AssertionError: Do not use tf.reset_default_graph() to clear nested graphs. If you need a cleared graph, exit the nesting and create a new graph.

This happens when you try to reset a graph with tensorflow session still active
and i am kind of lost about where i opened the session troubling me and what i named it. Now, i dont want to restart the kernel. I just want all the open sessions to terminate. How do i go about doing it?